# Display current Page number after/before

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, uipagecontrol

I was faced with the problem displaying the **current page**. I use **scrollView** with **pageControl** and i have a **label** on which i display **current page** and **total pages.** If i scroll on next image my label are change **+ 1 page,** but if i scroll on previous page my label don't change on **- 1**, my label are change only if i scroll twice on previous page.

My code is here:

```
class ScrollImageViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollImage: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfPagesLabel: UILabel!

    private var imageView: UIImageView!

    var imagesArray = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.pageControl.numberOfPages = imagesArray.count

        self.numberOfPagesLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        self.numberOfPagesLabel.clipsToBounds = true
        self.numberOfPagesLabel.text = "\(self.pageControl.currentPage)/\(self.imagesArray.count)"

        for i in 0..<imagesArray.count {

            imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imagesArray[i]))
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.scrollImage.frame.width, height: self.scrollImage.frame.height)

            scrollImage.contentSize.width = scrollImage.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
            scrollImage.addSubview(imageView)

        }
    }
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let currentPage = scrollImage.contentOffset.x / UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

        if pageControl.currentPage < imagesArray.count {
            self.pageControl.currentPage += 1
            self.numberOfPagesLabel.text = "\(self.pageControl.currentPage + 1)/\(self.imagesArray.count)"
        } else if pageControl.currentPage != 0 {
            self.pageControl.currentPage -= 1
            self.numberOfPagesLabel.text = "\(self.pageControl.currentPage - 1)/\(self.imagesArray.count)"
        }    
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(currentPage)
    }
}
```

And .gif for a better understanding, look at the label above the image

[image: .gi]

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3+:** Try below line of code.

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let currentPage = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
        self.pageControl.currentPage = Int(currentPage)

    }
```

**Another way to implement this by using UICollectionView**

Call these Delegate and Datasource
    **UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate** and UICollectionView Scroll Direction change into **Horizontal**

```
@IBOutlet var collectionViewItem: UICollectionView!

@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
var arrayImage = NSArray()

//MARK: ====: CollectionView DataSource :====
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayImage.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as! YourCollectionCell
        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: arrayImage[indexPath.row] as! String)
        return cell
    }

    //MARK: ====: CollectionView Delegate :====
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: collectionView.width, height: Your Height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

    //MARK: ====: UIScrollView Delegate :====
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let count = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
        self.pageControl.currentPage = Int(count)

    }
```

Comment: Please make sure you enabled paging of scrollview "scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true"

Comment: PagingEndabled I had enabled earlier in main.storyBoard

Answer (score 0):

You are already increase and decrease    `currentPage`      with 
   `self.pageControl.currentPage += 1` and              `self.pageControl.currentPage -= 1`

Still you are  doing             `self.numberOfPagesLabel.text = "\(self.pageControl.currentPage + 1)/\(self.imagesArray.count)"`

Here `self.pageControl.currentPage + 1` is wrong it should be

`self.pageControl.currentPage`

Full Code

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let currentPage = scrollImage.contentOffset.x / UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

    if pageControl.currentPage < imagesArray.count {
        self.pageControl.currentPage += 1
        self.numberOfPagesLabel.text = "\(self.pageControl.currentPage)/\(self.imagesArray.count)"
    } else if pageControl.currentPage != 0 {
        self.pageControl.currentPage -= 1
        self.numberOfPagesLabel.text = "\(self.pageControl.currentPage)/\(self.imagesArray.count)"
    }    
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(currentPage)
}
```

Hope it is helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

- Same problem occured with me too, I tried the following and it
  worked
- Initialised currentPageNum = 1
- In the scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(...),
  currentPageNum = Int(round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width))+1
- I guess by ContentOffset calculation, num of pages start from 0.